# Call constructor with unlimited parametes

Tags: c#, constructor

If I have a class called `MyObject` and I want to pass a variable number of parameters to it. How do I create make this available? Sometimes only using name, sometimes using everything.

I am using c# and 4.0

```
MyObject

  int Id
  string name
  datetime creationdate
  int createbyid
  int modifiedbyid
  datetime modifieddate
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be easiest to use the [object initialization syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx).

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject() { Id = 27, Name = "Daniel" };
```

If you want something to be required, use a constructor argument.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might make some people cringe, but some will love it, because it gives you the benefit of [object initialization syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)-- total flexibility-- and in addition allows you to add validators, assign the parameters to private or readonly fields, and perform other run-time checks that are not possible with object initialization syntax.

Summary: Pass a single anonymous object containing the named parameters you want, then read them out using a bit of reflection.

First, create this extension method:

```
static class ObjectExtensions
{
    //Helper method for reading the properties from an anonymous class
    public static T Peek<T>(this object source, string propertyName) 
    {
        var prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, typeof(T));
        return (prop == null) ? default(T) : (T)prop.GetValue(source);
    }
}
```

Then, define your class with a single constructor argument, typed as an `object`.  Write code to read the values out using the `Peek` method we just wrote:

```
class MyClass
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly int _id;
    private readonly double _optional;

    public MyClass(object o)
    {
        _name = o.Peek<string>("Name");
        _id = o.Peek<int>("ID");
        _optional = o.Peek<double>("Optional");
    }

    public void ProveThatItWorked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID = '{0}' Name = '{1}' Optional='{2}'", _id, _name, _optional));
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate `MyClass` using an anonymous type, with whatever parameters you want, like this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(new { Name = "My Name", ID = 17 });
c.ProveThatItWorked();
```

Using this technique, you can pass as many named parameters as you want in that anonymous object, as long as you have `Peek` statements to read them. If a parameter isn't included in the anonymous type, it'll just come back as the default for that parameter's data type. If you include a parameter that isn't used, it'll just get ignored.

You can even pass it a row from a LINQ query if you want, making it very powerful for domain-type objects:

```
var list = from t in db.table
           select new { ID = t.SomeIdentifier, Name = t.SomeName };
foreach (var i in list) {
    var c = new MyClass(i);
    c.ProveThatItWorked();
}
```

Try *that* with object initialization syntax.

Caveats:

- It is generally frowned upon to define extension methods on `object` because of intellisense pollution.  Has never bothered me too much personally.
- This approach will not catch most mistakes at compile-time (e.g. if you try to pass a `string` where an `int` was expected). This will really bother a lot of people, although it is totally the norm in the Javascript world or in other [duck-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) languages.  But if you'd like compile-time checking, just define your own class instead of using an anonymous class, and pass that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different constructors for each scenario you would like to cover.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string name)
    {

    }

    public MyClass(string name, DateTime creationDate)
    {

    }
}
```

This way you can prevent your object from being constructed with an incorrect initial state.